# Using FEM and NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I have to solve the ODE
$u''[t]+u'[t]+\sin {(5t)} u[t]=t^3-t$, with $u[0]=0,u[1]=0,$ with a finite element method and then with `NDSolve`.

Finally, I have to calculate $|u_{FEM}-u_{NDSolve}|$ and if the inequality

$\sqrt {\int_{a}^{b}[u(t)]^2dt} \le \frac{b-a}{\sqrt 2} \sqrt {\int_{a}^{b}[u_t(t)]^2dt}$ holds for $b=1,a=0.$

I used:

```
ic1 = {u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0};
ode = u''[t] + u'[t] + Sin[5 t] u[t] == t^3 - t;
sol = NDSolve[{ode, ic1}, u, {t, 0, 20}, 
Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
  MeshOptions -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}][[1]];
bctraditional = {u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0};
soltraditional = NDSolve[{ode, bctraditional}, u, {t, 0, 20}][[1]];

Plot[Evaluate[u[t] /. {sol, soltraditional}], {t, 0, 20}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, 
PlotStyle -> {Automatic, {Red, Dashed}}]
```

On the other hand, I used:

```
sol = NDSolve[{u''[t] + u'[t] + Sin[5 t] u[t] == t^3 - t, u[0] == 0, 
u[1] == 0}, u[t], t]
Plot[u[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1}]
```

but I couldn't find an expression for $u[t]$ and not the same results and not able to apply the integrals. Any help? Thank you

Comment: What's $u_{FED}$?  That is, is FED supposed to be FEM?

Comment: Yes, u are right, I corrected it

Comment: Any help for the last two questions?

Answer (score 5):

What about using `NDSolveValue`? It can directly return the interpolating function:

```
ode = u''[t] + u'[t] + Sin[5 t] u[t] == t^3 - t;
uFEM = NDSolveValue[{ode, DirichletCondition[u[t] == 0, True]}, 
   u, 
   {t, 0, 1}, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement","MeshOptions" -> MaxCellMeasure -> 0.001}
   ];
utraditional = NDSolveValue[{ode, u[0] == 0, u[1] == 0}, u, {t, 0, 1}];
```

Notice the use of `DirichletCondition` to get FEM working. As far as I understood the user interface, `"FiniteElement"` can only handle Dirichlet conditions if they really lie on the boundary. Thus `{t, 0, 20}` won't work correctly.

Now you can use `uFEM` and `utraditional` like any other function `u`, i.e., you do not have to mess around with `ReplaceAll` (`/.`). For example:

```
Plot[uFEM[t] - utraditional[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Sqrt[NIntegrate[uFEM[t]^2, {t, 0, 1}]] <= 
 Sqrt[NIntegrate[uFEM'[t]^2, {t, 0, 1}]]/Sqrt[2]
Sqrt[NIntegrate[utraditional[t]^2, {t, 0, 1}]] <= 
 Sqrt[NIntegrate[utraditional'[t]^2, {t, 0, 1}]]/Sqrt[2]
```

> True
>
> True

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me with the last two questions?

Comment: @George the [FEM Options tutorial](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementOptions.html#1993509248) has a section on what triggers the use FEM in `NDSolve`. Perhaps useful.